# I already installed haystack on my visual code I used pip install farm-haystack. But I am still getting error when I am importing libraries

Tags: python, import, importerror, openai-api, haystack

```
Import "haystack.file_converter.pdf" could not be resolved
Import "haystack.document_store.memory" could not be resolved
Import "haystack.retriever.sparse" could not be resolved
```

I already tried changing my environment to what's compatible to haystack, uninstalling and installing haystack again but still not working, please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Hi... Please share the installation command you used and also the code that raises these errors...